# SQL Server Adding Sequence to Select Statement

Tags: sql-server, loops, select

I have a `Select` statement that pulls customer information i.e. `CustomerID`, `FirstName`, `LastName`, etc.

I want to be able to assign a sales person to the best 100 customers ranked by sales.

I have the select statement set up to pull the best 100 customers, how would I add a column to the statement that numbers the customers in such a way:

```
SalesID 
1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4...
```

Where my sales people ID is repeated over and over for all records.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `row_number()` and modulus arithmetic:

```
select t.*,
       1 + (row_number() over (order by . . . ) % 4)
from t
order by . . .
```

The `. . .` is for the ordering columns that specify "best".  This should be the same for both `order by` clauses.

Note that some databases use `mod()` instead of `%`.